# Flutter chatbot HandshakeException when accessing DialogFlowAPI

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, handshake, sslhandshakeexception

The bot is built using DialogFlow + Flutter and the package used is https://pub.dev/packages/dialog_flowtter version 0.3.0-nullsafety.0
The app works relatively fine as long as you type, but as soon as you stop writing it gives the exception mentioned. I am located in Romania, eastern Europe, I have read somewhere that it might be because of the location and others mentioned about the https certificate. Currently I have used correctly the auth.json file as far as I know. Thanks in advance

The exception is throwed from the file dialog.dart.

```
async {
if (_client == null) await _updateHttpClient();

var body = HttpUtil.getBody(
  queryParams: queryParams,
  queryInput: queryInput,
  audioConfig: audioConfig,
);

var response = await _client.post(
  '$kDialogFlowUrl/$kDialogFlowApiVersion/${HttpUtil.getFormatedSession(projectId, sessionId)}:detectIntent',
  body: jsonEncode(body),
);
```

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzIou.png)
[Same exception but in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghzGV.png)

Comment: I too have same problem. But it works in Android 9 but not in 11.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Hi, yes!! I don't recall exactly the way I solved it though...

Comment: I am having the same problem. I don't know how to solve it? I created an issue in their github. but no replies.